# How to centre Nav bar and main content and footer

Tags: html, css

I am very new to the world of web coding and require some assistance. I am making a webpage for the local sports team as their one doesn't look great and Wordpress is not very user friendly, so I decided it was probably easier to try coding it myself.

I cannot get my Navbar, main content and Footer to be entered on the page. I would like the Navbar, main content and footer to be entered and only 80% width so you will see some of the background which will be a picture of the sports team players)

```
     #footerWrapper { max-width: 80%;
         max-height: 5%;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     line-height: 30px;
     font-size: 0.9em;
     border: 0 solid #ddd;
     border-bottom-color: #3F8444;
     border-width: 1px 0;}
         /*Positions and Margins*/
       .image {
         position: absolute; 
         top:100px; 
         left:100px;
         }
        .image-1 {
         position: absolute;
         top:20px;
         right: 100px;
         }
         header{
             text-align: center;
             margin-top: 100px;
             margin-bottom: 100px;
         }
        main{ width: 80%;
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: row;
             justify-content: space-evenly;
             align-items: center;}
         footer{ 
           position: static;
         left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
         width: 80%;
     height: 5%;}
        p {margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;}
         /*Navigation*/
         ul { display: flex;
             flex-direction: row;
         align-items: center;
           list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           overflow: hidden;
           background-color: #04AA6D;
           width: 80%;
         }
         
         /*li {float: left;}*/
         
         li a, .dropdown li a {
           display: block;
           color: white;
           text-align: center;
           padding: 14px 16px;
           text-decoration: none;
         }
         
         li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #111;}
         
         li.dropdown {
             display: inline-block;}
         
         .dropdown-content { 
             display:none;
             position: absolute;
             background-color: #04AA6D;
             color: white;
             min-width: 160px;
             box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0,.2);
             z-index: 1;
         }
         .dropdown-content a
         {
             color: white;
             padding: 12px 16px;
             text-decoration: none;
             display: block;
             text-align: left;
         }
         .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #111;color: white;}
         .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
         {
             display: block;
         }
         </style>    
 </div>
 </head>
 <body>
     <header>
         <div class="image" id="Sports Team logo">
         <img src="Sport Teams logo">
     </div>
     <div class="image-1" id="Club logo">
         <img src="Club logo" width="246" height="237">
     </div>
         <h1>Sports Team</h1>
     </header>
     <nav>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="Sports Team url link">Home</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a class="dropbtn">Club Info</a>
           <div class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="Sports Team url link">About Us</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Committee</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Contact Us</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Game Rules</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Uniforms</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Fair Play</a>
             <a href="Sports Team url link">Terms and Conditions</a>
           </div>
         <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropbtn">Winter Season 2023</a>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="Sports Team url link">Training Information</a>
           <a href="Sports Team url link">Game Details</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Registration</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Season Info Pack</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Handbook</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Privacy Policy</a>
                 </div>
         <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropbtn">Summer Season 2023</a>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Training Information</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Game Details</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Registration</a>
               <a href="Sports Team url link">Season Info Pack</a>
                   </div>
           <li><a href="Sports Team url link">Umpire Information</a>
       </ul>
     </nav>
 <Div></Div>
 <main>
   <div class="main">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>Sports Team email</p>
    </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried a lot of different CSS styles float, margins, flex, grid etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Great work! This is a really good start. It seems like you are getting the hang out it. I strongly recommend looking into a framework like [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/).

These frameworks help to take care of most of this tedious fine-tuning. You wouldn't really have much CSS in your files you would add class names. Something like `class="m-auto d-flex text-center"` would take the place of all your css.

These frameworks are based on classes which is my next recommendation. You should use classes or ids for everything. This is how you will be able to write cleaner more organized code. You should have:

```html
<style>
   .nav_bar { }
</style>

<ul class="nav_bar">
 ...
</ul>
```

What if you need to have more than one `ul` on your site but they need different colors or the other shouldn't be centered?

Here is how you can center your existing code:
The margin on your navbar and main should be auto instead of 0.

```css
 main { width: 80%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto;
 }

 ul { display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      width: 80%;
 }
```